# preg_match pipe sign

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression

```
|^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$|
```

Which match `/php/anything`.

Now I want a regular expression which match both

```
/php/anything
/java/anything
```

I tired `|^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$|` but its not working.

Can someone help me with solution?
I want to keep all other part but change just `(php)` part.

Here is the code

```
preg_match("|^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$|", 'php/anything')
```

But I get this warning and match doesn't work

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'j'
```

Thanks

Comment: Your regular expression isn't very elegant but it seems to work: http://rubular.com/r/J2mE8vdhjb  What specifically is the problem? Can you post some code?

Comment: what exactly do you want to match..we can help clean your regex..

Comment: Or we can just take  (php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/? part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `|` as the regex delimiter but you have a `|` inside the regex as alteration, which you need to escape. If you don't the 2nd `|` is treated as the end of regex and the letter following it `j` is treated as regex modifier. Since `j` is not a valid modifier, you get the error.

You escape the `|` as:

```
preg_match("|^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php\|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$|", 'php/anything')
                                ^
```

Or you can use a different pair of delimiter:

```
preg_match("~^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$~", 'php/anything')
            ^                                           ^
```

Comment: In URL there can be only php OR java.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you are using pipe signs as the characters delimiting your pattern.  Thus you need to escape a pipe sign within the pattern itself, or just change the delimiter to something else that you won't be using in your pattern:

```
#^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$#
{^(/[a-z]{2})?/?(php|java)/([-a-z0-9]+)/?/?$}
```

etc.